# How to display a really long form in a user-friendly way?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I got a table in my database with 81 fields or more. The user actually has to fill the data in all these fields. I need to design my formview for this data in a user friendly way.

I thought of adding a `TabContainer` within my formview but i read online that this causes a problem on inserting and a manual look-up for each control is required which is almost impossible in my case to look-up 80 fields.

Any suggestions on how to do that ?

Comment: You could use an accordion.

Comment: You mean to update each view within the accordion separately, right?

Comment: Theoretically it won't matter, as you can use the TextChanged to just update the controls that needed to.  You will be sending a lot back anyway, but at least it looks more manageable for the user AND sort of promotes that the users presses the "SAVE" between sections - reducing risk of loss.

Answer (score 0):

Accordion Sample:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="MyAccordion" runat="server" 
                       SelectedIndex="0" 
                       HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" 
                       ContentCssClass="accordionContent" 
                       FadeTransitions="true" 
                       FramesPerSecond="40" 
                       TransitionDuration="250"
                       AutoSize="None">
 <Panes>
      <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID = "AccordionPane1" runat = "server">
      <Header>
        <a href = "" onclick = "return false;" class = "accordionLink"> Section 1</a>
      </Header>
      <Content>
        <p>This book is about to be release on a very difficult subject to find good detailed info on.</p>
        <p><img align = "left" alt = "" border = "0" src = "http://www.joeon.net/blogfiles/DOTNETInternational.jpg"></p>
        <p class = "MsoNormal"><b><font color = "#000000" face = "Arial" size = "2">
        <span style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; color: navy; font-family: Arial">
        .NET Internationalization: The Developer's Guide to Building Global Windows and Web Applications
        </span></font></b></p>
        <p class = "MsoNormal"><font color = "#000000" face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; color: navy; font-family: Arial">
        By Smith-Ferrier, Guy
        </span></font></p>
        <p class = "MsoNormal"><font color = "#000000" face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; color: navy; font-family: Arial">
        Published by Addison-Wesley
        </span></font></p>
        <p class = "MsoNormal"><font color = "#000000" face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; color: navy; font-family: Arial">
        Series: Microsoft .NET Development Series
        </span></font></p>
        <p class = "MsoNormal"><font color = "#000000"><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; color: navy; font-family: Arial">
        ISBN: 0321341384; Published: 
        </span></font>
        <font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; color: navy; font-family: Arial">
        8/11/2006
        </span></font><font face = "Arial"size = "2">
        <span style = "font-size: 10pt; color: navy; font-family: Arial">
        ; Copyright 2007; Pages: T; Edition: 1
        </span></font></font></p>
        <p class = "MsoNormal"><font color = "navy" face = "Arial" size = "2">
        <span style = "font-size: 10pt; color: navy; font-family: Arial">
        <a href = "http://www.awprofessional.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=0321341384&amp;rl=1" target = "_blank"><font color = "#000000">http://www.awprofessional.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=0321341384&amp;rl=1</font></a> </span></font></p>
        <p class = "MsoNormal"><font color = "navy" face = "Arial" size = "2">
        <span style = "font-size: 10pt; color: navy; font-family: Arial">
        <a href = "http://www.joeon.net/blogfiles/SmithFerrier.pdf">You can click HERE for a sample chapter. </a></span></font></p>
      </Content>
    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>

    <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID = "AccordionPane2" runat = "server">
      <Header>
        <a href = "" onclick = "return false;" class = "accordionLink"> Section 2</a>
      </Header>
      <Content>
        <p>
        <img align = "left" alt = "Clown" border = "0" src = "http://www.joeon.net/blogfiles/Clown.jpg">Last week
        we but a form up on www.asp.net so that folks could send requests for How-Do-I video topics. Today I
        recieved the folowing thoughtful feedback from a values customer.</p>
        <p>"Make new versions of all the videos without the ridiculous, yet highly annoying mouse click sounds...:-(((."</p>
        <p>To whoever the anonymous poster of that comment was, I replyâ€¦.</p>
        <p>Dear Sir, thanks for your feedback. Unfortunatly, I find it necesaary to use the mouse during the
        presentations, I will however begin trainer is the secret art of â€œstealth
        mousing.&nbsp;<img src = "http://www.joeon.net/blogfiles/smile1.gif">&nbsp;</p>
        <p>To the hundreds of other folks who have taken the time to send meaningful suggestions and feedback.</p>
        <p>MANY THANKS!</p>
        <p>I'm glad that you find the videos valuable and that you are liking asp.</p>
        <p>I'll be blogging about the suggestions. Please keep them coming.</p>
        <p>Joe</p>
      </Content>
    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>

    <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID = "AccordionPane3" runat = "server">
      <Header>
        <a href = "" onclick = "return false;" class = "accordionLink"> Section 3</a>
      </Header>
      <Content>
        <p><img align = "left" alt = "Bill_Hilf" border = "0" src = "http://www.joeon.net/blogfiles/Bill_Hilf.gif">It's
        <a href = "http://www.microsoft.com/technet/community/tnradio/bio/billhilf.mspx" target = "_blank"> Bill
        Hilf, Microsoft General Manager of Platform Strategy</a>.</p>
        <p> There was allot of press over the last few weeks about the
        <a href = "http://news.com.com/2100-1014_3-6086044.html" target = "_blank">sudden departure of Martin Taylor. </a></p>
        <p>I've had several questions about what this means as Martin was influential in Microsoft strategy and close to Steve Ballmer.</p>
        <p>In actuality, Martin moved out of platform strategy some time ago and Bill's been the man for a number of months already.</p
        <p>I had several conversations with Martin and he is a very bright guy.</p>
        <p>But I've had lots of conversations with Bill and he is a REALLY bright guy. (In fact Iâ€™ll be on stage with Bill this weekend at the Microsoft Global Technology Exchange.)</p>
        <p>I almost went to work for Bill last year but he really needed me in Redmond and I just wasnâ€™t ready to move yet.</p>
        <p>So keep your eye out for Bill. In the wake of Bill's announcement a few weeks ago were all looking to see how Microsoft thought leadership re-aligns.</p>
      </Content>
    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>

    <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID = "AccordionPane4" runat = "server">
      <Header>
        <a href = "" onclick = "return false;" class = "accordionLink"> Section 4</a>
      </Header>
      <Content>
        <p>
        <font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">
        <img align = "left" alt = "MurachCS2005" border = "0" src = "http://www.joeon.net/blogfiles/MurachCS2005.jpg"></span></font></p>
        <p><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">I read A LOT of developer books. Many I like, many I loath. </span></font></p>
        <p><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial"></span> </font></p>
        <p><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">If I were going to
        teach a course on C#, I would probably choose Murachâ€™s C# 2005 as the
        textbook.&nbsp;</span></font><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">&nbsp;</span></font></p>
        <p><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">Unlike most technical
        books, this book is writing as a training resource. So while it makes a great â€œtextbookâ€, itâ€™s a â€œHow Do
        focused learning resource. </span></font></p>
        <p><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial"></span> </font></p>
        <p><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">But UNLIKE a lot of
        textbooks, it is easy to read (and therefore learn from), itâ€™s up-to-date, including detailed coverage of
        the latest C# 2.0 language constructs, and it has a commercial programming feel so itâ€™s goal is not simply
        to provide academic coverage of the programming language, but rather how to write good code with
        C#</span></font><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">&nbsp;</span></font></p>
        <p><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">Wanna learn C# ? Wanna
        learn more about C#? Want a great desk reference for C#? </span> </font></p>
        <p><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial"></span> </font></p>
        <p><font face = "Arial" size = "2"><span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial">Buying this book
        should be a no-brainer !</span></font></p>
      </Content>
    </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane>
 </Panes>
 </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
```